# Command not working to import backup file in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using Ubuntu and and trying to use this below command to get database from dump file:

mysql --h localhost --u root --p deepak slu < \home\slu.sql

But above this not working.

What text is wrong here.

Regards

Comment: Which error do you get? What's wrong?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql --h localhost --u root --p deepak slu <' at line 1

Comment: Kindly suggest any other command to get db from sql dump files. Me also searching google if you know on the tip then let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you're using wrong parameters.
Try with this:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=deepak slu < \home\slu.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the mysql man page, you should have an equal sign after `--` parameters. Furthermore, `--` parameters need to be fully written out. Try changing your command to this:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=root --password=deepak slu < \home\slu.sql
```